# `sickle` binary 'not found' after Conda installation

Tags: conda, bioinformatics

I am running whole genome sequencing analysis on a number of samples and I am using Conda to install `sickle` (version 0.7.0). The package does not seem to be found despite that it was successfully installed.

Here are the steps I followed:

- installed Miniconda3 (version 4.14.0) and created an environment using `conda env create -n package`.
- activated conda environment using `conda activate package`
- installed sickle with required version 0.7.0 using `conda install -c bioconda sickle=0.7.0`
- checked whether this was successfully installed using `conda list`. This returned:

```
# packages in environment at /home/miniconda3/envs/package:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h7f8727e_1002  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2022.07.19           h06a4308_0  
certifi                   2022.6.15       py310h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h74dc2b5_0  
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
cryptography              37.0.1          py310h9ce1e76_0  
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3  
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h7f8727e_2  
libxml2                   2.9.14               h74e7548_0  
libxslt                   1.1.35               h4e12654_0  
lxml                      4.9.1           py310h1edc446_0  
ncurses                   6.3                  h5eee18b_3  
openssl                   1.1.1q               h7f8727e_0  
pip                       22.1.2          py310h06a4308_0  
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310h06a4308_0  
python                    3.10.4               h12debd9_0  
readline                  8.1.2                h7f8727e_1  
requests                  2.28.1          py310h06a4308_0  
setuptools                63.4.1          py310h06a4308_0  
sickle                    0.7.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    bioconda
sqlite                    3.39.2               h5082296_0  
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0  
urllib3                   1.26.11         py310h06a4308_0  
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7f8727e_1  
zlib                      1.2.12               h7f8727e_2
```

- tried to call `sickle` on command line:

```bash
$ sickle --help

Command 'sickle' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install sickle
Please ask your administrator.
```

Would someone please assist me or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, bioinformatics users should use a Mambaforge base install. We never want to use the `defaults` channel (instead `conda-forge` should have top priority) and the community has largely embraced Mamba as a superior frontend to Conda.

Answer (score 1):

The Bioconda package `sickle` delivers [the `Sickle` Python package](https://pypi.org/project/Sickle/) and doesn't look like anything for NGS data processing. It only has a Python API - no CLI/entrypoint.

Instead, you likely want [the Bioconda package `sickle-trim`](https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/sickle-trim/README.html), which corresponds to [a C-based FASTQ trimmer called `sickle`](https://github.com/najoshi/sickle), and delivers a binary (CLI).

```bash
mamba install -c bioconda sickle-trim
```